# Why my delegate programs giving me an error?

Tags: c#, delegates

I tried this program it's working fine.

```
class MyProgram
{
    delegate string StrMode(string s);

    static string ReplaceSpace(string s)
    {
        return s.Replace(' ', '-');
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a Method Group Conversion example.");

        StrMode sm = ReplaceSpace;
        string str1 = sm("This is a test.");
        Console.WriteLine(str1);
    }
}
```

The above program gives me the nicest output, But i thought to make something new to which two classes could tend to call using the delegates method as i do below the programs but that makes me SICK and giving me unkind of invoking errors, please help, i want to play delegates using two class, So is that possible?

```
delegate string StrMod(string s);

public class MyProgram1
{
    public static string ReverseString(string s)
    {
        string temp = "";
        int i, j;
        for (j = 0, i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--, j++)            
            temp = temp + s[i];

        return temp;
    }
}

public class MyProgram2
{
    public static string RemoveSpace(string s)
    {
        string temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)            
            if (s[i] != ' ')
                temp = temp + s[i];

        return temp;
    }
}

class MainProgram
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //creating an object for class 1..
        MyProgram1 mp1 = new MyProgram1();
        string str;

        StrMod str = mp1.ReverseString;
        string str2 = str("This is test.");
        Console.WriteLine(str2);
    }
}
```

**Edited**

Here is my error:

[image]

Comment: What are the errors? Also, Please add indentation

Comment: Please, spend some time improving formatting of your code

Comment: Thanks but will you help me, I do believe in codings logic, but not in Formatting.. Sorry but don't get me as Wrong :)

Comment: @mehirmehta: If you can't be bothered to present code in a readable format, why should anyone be bothered to help you? Your code is hard to read, therefore your post is hard to read, therefore people will move on to a question where the person asking it actually respects the time of the people trying to help.

Comment: Additionally, if you're getting errors you should say what they are. "giving me unkind of invoking errors" isn't nearly enough details.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Here is my [error](http://postimg.org/image/x4zzjxlab/)

Comment: @HassanNisar: i respect to your reputation but I don't understand what you're trying to say man?

Comment: Showing an error as a picture is *much* less useful than just copying and pasting the text into your question, explaining what line it's on. Now that we've seen the error though, it looks like you should have been able to understand it...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, I need to go inside the depth.. by the way jon i like your book `Depth in C#` .. really nice programs there to clear my doubt.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already defined local variable with name `str`. You cannot use same name for delegate variable:

```
string str; // first definition    
StrMod str = mp1.ReverseString; // same name (also another issue - see below)
```

After you changed question, reason of error is that your `ReverseString` method is static, but you are using it as instance method. You don't need to create and use instance of `MyProgram1`  class. You should use class name to access static members:

```
StrMod str = MyProgram1.ReverseString;
```

---

BTW error message is pretty self-descriptive:

> Member 'MyProgram1.ReverseString(string)' cannot be accessed with an
>   instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

It even has a hint of what you should do to fix error.

Comment: True - although that's not the only issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks Jon, updated. With original formatting it was hard to see anything :)

Comment: `qualify it with a type name instead` that's making me sick!!.. :p

Comment: @mehirmehta that's how static members should be used. That's a members defined for type, not for some particular instance of type.

Comment: Sorry, But i'm using a `static` in every method as you could see above into my codes man.. :)

Comment: @mehirmehta: Why is it "making you sick"? Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I get confused `qualify it with a type name` ..that line makes me sick.. :)